# Want to Calculate Hightest Pay Value For a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a list of employees who
have worked on the activity that has the highest Total Pay value.

don't use code such as …where actid = 151…ect

• Note: Total Pay worked for an activity is the sum of the (Total Hours Worked * matching
Hourly Rate)
(e.g. Total Pay for Activity 151 is 10.5 hrs @ $50.75 + 11.5 hrs @ $25 + 3hrs @ $33,)

You must use a subquery in your
solution.

```
ACTID   HRSWORKED   HOURLYRATE  Total Pay
163     10             45.5     455
163     8              45.5     364
163     6              45.5     273
151     5              50.75    253.75
151     5.5            50.75    279.125
155     10             30       300
155     10             30       300
165     20             25       500
155     10             30       300
155     8              27       216
151     11.5           25       287.5
151     1              33       33
151     1              33       33
151     1              33       33
```

You time and effort much appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: Make a view using JOIN and apply highest value for a column for that view.

Comment: You should first try by your self

Comment: Looks like homework.

Comment: I havn't got much idea about view

Comment: I think you forgot to add a table with the employee details

Comment: select a.empid,a.empname,a.hrsworked,a.hourlyrate,actid,a.acdescription,m.empgender,(hrsworked*hourlyrate) as "Total Pay"
from action a
inner join employee m
on m.empid=a.empid
where (hrsworked*hourlyrate) >(select max(hourlyrate) from action);

I tried this but i won't work properly :( :(

Answer (score 0):

Without knowledge of the schema, I can only provide a possible sketch (you'll have to compute total pay and provide all necessary JOINs and predicates):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(employee id) -- reconfigure if more then just employee id
FROM <table(s)> 
[WHERE...]
{ WHERE | AND } total pay = (SELECT MAX(total pay) 
                             FROM <table(s)>
                             [WHERE...]);
```

I used `DISTINCT` because it's possible to have more than one activity with the same `MAX` value and overlapping employees. If you're including `ACTID` in the output, then you won't need `DISTINCT` because the same employee shouldn't be on a project twice (unless they are tracked by roles on a project in which case a single employee might have multiple roles - it all depends on the data set).

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you're referring to. If the brackets and dots are confusing, then I apologize (it's based on [Backus-Naur form](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/ap_syntx002.htm#SQLRF55396) which is common in database syntax). Replace `<tables(s)>` with the names, if you need additional predicates, put them where `[WHERE...]` is (square brackets mean optional). If you used `WHERE` already, then you use `AND` (that's what the curly braces and `|` means). It is just pseudo code since I don't have any particulars on your schema, thus I cannot produce actual SQL.